# Lookup column in sharepoint list column in visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I've a list with two columns as *student Id* and *student name*. In second list am taking one column as lookup and giving reference to student name. But while inserting record in second list when am selecting student name and clicked save ,in second list I've to save *student Id* not *student name*. (just like dropdown in asp.net data text field and data value field.)

How can I achieve this in SharePoint using lookup column and am creating the second list in visual studio?

Answer (score 3):

Just give **Student Name** field in lookup field as shown below.
[image]